# Generating multi-level JSON javasacript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I've never used JSON before so I'm not familiar with its syntax.

At the moment I have multiple arrays containing different pieces of data.

I would like to create one JSON object, that contains the multiple arrays each with several pieces of data.

I have an array of Objects, example :

```
{parent_name: "Table 1", child_name: "Table 1.1", documentNo: "BEC32568/17"}

{parent_name: "Table 1", child_name: "Table 1.1", documentNo: "BEC32607/17"}

{parent_name: "Table 1", child_name: "Table 1.2", documentNo: "BEC32613/17"}
```

I want to convert like this :

```
[{
  "parent_name": "Table 1",
  "childs_name": [{ // childs with s

      "child_name": "Table 1.1", // child without s
      "documentsNo": // Documents with s 
      [
        {
          "documentNo": "BEC32568/17" // Document without s
        },
        {
          "documentNo": "BEC32607/17"
        }
      ]

    },

    {
      "childs_name": "Table 1.2",
      "DocumentsNo":
      [
        {
          "DocumentNo": "BEC32613/17"
        }
      ]

    }]
}]
```

How can I create a multilevel JSON object in javascript !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well JSON is a file format created for exchanging javascript object information.

Here is a vanilla JS way to do it. You could do something a bit fancier with a library like Ramda or underscore

```
var input = [{parent_name: "Table 1", child_name: "Table 1.1", documentNo: "BEC32568/17"},
{parent_name: "Table 1", child_name: "Table 1.1", documentNo: "BEC32607/17"},
{parent_name: "Table 1", child_name: "Table 1.2", documentNo: "BEC32613/17"}];

var output = [];

input.forEach((document) => {
  var parent = output.find(table => table.parent_name === document.parent_name);
  if (!parent) {
    parent = { parent_name: document.parent_name, childs_name: [] };
    output.push(parent);
  }
  var child = parent.childs_name.find(child => child.child_name === document.child_name);
  if (!child) {
    child = { child_name: document.child_name, documentNo: [] };
    parent.childs_name.push(child);
  }
  child.documentNo.push({ documentNo: document.documentNo });
});


var outputJSON = JSON.stringify(output, null, 2);

console.log(outputJSON);
```

Comment: I try this before but i didn't get the result i want. thankx for your reply !

Comment: @JohnDoe Okay I read your question a little closer and updated my answer